# Setting Timestamp column to NULL on Insert In DB2

Tags: sql, types, casting, db2

I'm using DB2 version 10. I have a table with a timestamp for updates defined for me as follows in the Create Table statement :

```
Update_Timestamp             For Column D2TIMSTU Timestamp    DEFAULT  NULL
```

On initial load of the data to this table, I want to set the value of this column to NULL for all rows, but I have not been successful. I have tried specifying NULL as the insert value and I have even tried specifying DEFAULT.

Both attempts gave the same error :

> SQL State: 42703
>   Vendor Code: -206
>   Message: [SQL0206] Column or global variable DEFAULT not found. Cause . . . . . . :   DEFAULT was not found as a column of table *N in *N and was not found as a global variable in *N.

If the table is *N, DEFAULT is not a column of any table or view that can be reference

> Same error for NULL - replacing NULL for DEFAULT in the error message.

I know I can get around this by just not specifying the column name and value, but I'd really like to know why this won't work.

Comment: what does the INSERT statement look like ?

Comment: INSERT INTO [Table Name](col1, col2, col3)SELECT Value1, Value2, NULL FROM [Source Table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, are you sure that col3 in the destination table is allowed to accept NULL values ?

If so, try something like this (I cant test--I dont have access to a DB2 system anymore)

```
INSERT INTO [Table Name](col1, col2, col3)SELECT Value1, Value2, 
    cast(NULL as timestamp) FROM [Source Table]
```

Comment: I gave the definition of column3 above as Update_Timestamp For Column D2TIMSTU Timestamp DEFAULT NULL  So yes, it will accept a NULL.  Will try your suggestion, but not sure why you would need to cast as the type should come from the column definition itself

Comment: I just recall that DB2 is so strongly typed, so you may need to specify what kind of column your NULL is

Comment: OK - that worked - and to test to see if this just happened on a column defined as a timestamp, I tried setting a nullable integer column to NULL without casting, and got the same error.  Marked as answer - thanks.

Comment: Okay, this explains why I was having this exact problem too.